# Callback Argument assuming class notation

Tags: c++, class, callback, signature, asynccallback

I have an extract method defined on an API, that is expecting an ID and a callback funcion.

`extractAsync(const std::string &name, void (*callback)(int)`

but i'm defining the callback function inside the class because **i need access to other things inside it**.

`class CommandBuilder { public: //... void onExtractionChanged(int result); }`

My problem is that, because it is inside the class, when i pass as argument it says invalid argument type.

`argument of type "void (CommandBuilder::*)(int result)" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(int)"`

(I've simplified some of the code in order to explain the problem, if you have any other doubts please ask)

What i've tried:

- Lambda functions;
- Removing from the class (don't have access to other things that i need and can't pass them as argument aswell)
- Adding to the class (gives that weird error because instead of being 'void (*)(int)' it becomes 'void (CommandBuilder::*)(int result)' )

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function and a pointer to a (non-static) member function is just not the same. They are not compatible and can't be used interchangeably. Can you modify the `extractAsync` function? If not there's not really much you can do beyond making the object instance a global variable and use `static` member functions.

Comment: Can you modify the callback to pass a void pointer? Then you could use it to pass the `this` pointer back so you could use a static function.

Comment: Usually callbacks have a parameter of type `void*` which provides you with a value passed when registering it. Since the API doesn't seem to provide this functionality, your only option is to use a global (reference to your) object here...

Comment: you seem to be aware of the issue and possible solutions, what is missing is your code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Have you also simplified the callback interface? If so, please post the real one.

Comment: Hey guys, a friend was able to help me. The solution involved creating a wrapper inside of a lambda function. I think we can mark it as resolved. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: @IvoRibeiro If you think the solution could help others, then please write an actual answer that you can then accept.